# I cant figure out the issue in this code. Can anyone help me?

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the directory name from where you want to process the pdf documents"  
read fname 
for FILE in $fname/*.pdf
do
   echo $FILE
   outdir=../processedpdf
   mkdir -p "$outdir"
  java -jar tika-app-1.6.jar --xml "$FILE" >"$outdir/${FILE%.pdf}.xml" \
    || rm -- "$outdir/${FILE%.pdf}.xml"
done
```

I'm not able to establish another source file to execute the files, can anyone help me??
I cant assign a different folder-name to execute its files.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your script, it looks like you are trying to convert `pdf` files into `xml` file and store the converted files inside `processedpdf` directory.

I have made few modification to your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the directory name from where you want to process the pdf documents"  
read fname 

# Create directory only if it does not exist.
[[ -d ../processedpdf ]] || mkdir ../processedpdf

for FILE in "${fname}"/*.pdf
do
    echo "$FILE"
    java -jar tika-app-1.6.jar --xml "$FILE" > "$outdir/${FILE%.pdf}.xml"
done
```

The modifications which I have made are.

1. Have moved `mkdir ../processedpdf` outside of the loop as its unnecessary to repeat it.
2. You dont need `|| rm -- "$outdir/${FILE%.pdf}.xml"`. Because if the file conversion fails then the `"$outdir/${FILE%.pdf}.xml"` file will not be created at all and so it is not necessary to remove it.
3. Have changed you shell from `bourne` to `bash`.

Comment: How do i assign a different parent folder for converting its file from the command-line??

Comment: do you mean to create a different output directory for each converted file ?

Comment: The redirection causes the shell to create the output file before `java` even runs, so you assertion that the `rm` is unnecessary is not true.

Comment: Also trading `mkdir -p` for `test -d || mkdir` is hardly an improvement.

Comment: Reverting that also makes it unnecessary to switch to Bash since the only Bashism was the (gratuitous) `[[`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for FILE in $fname/*.pdf
> do
>    echo $FILE
>    outdir=../processedpdf
>    mkdir -p "$outdir"
>   java -jar tika-app-1.6.jar --xml "$FILE" >"$outdir/${FILE%.pdf}.xml" \
>     …
> ```
>
> How do i assign a different parent folder …

The problem with your code is that `$FILE` contains the path `$fname` and thus prepending `$outdir` doesn't yield the desired, but a probably inexistent folder path. Example:
`fname=R` ⇒ e. g. `FILE=R/Rplots.pdf` ⇒ `>"../processedpdf/R/Rplots.xml"`

To get the desired `$outdir` path, `$fname` has to be removed, e. g.

```
   BASEFILE=${FILE##*/}
   java -jar tika-app-1.6.jar --xml "$FILE" >"$outdir/${BASEFILE%.pdf}.xml" \
    …
```